# Who was the man that Suitengu called Master?

Tags: speed-grapher

In the 1st episode, as Kagura descends, there is an extravagant looking man watching the ceremony. In the 3rd episode, after Kagura and Saiga fall into the water, he shows up behind Suitengo commenting on Saiga's power and attempting to come up with a name for it. Suitengu refers to him as Master ______ (I don't remember his name).

I am wondering who this man was, as it seems he was important enough to be focused on during the ceremony and he knew right away Saiga had become a Euphoric.

Answer (score 1):

Went back, watched the scenes in question. I thought it was the ballet dancer from the 4th episode, would explain why you don't recognize him and why he doesn't play the prominent role you'd expect going forward.
If I'm right that makes him [Katsuya Shirogane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Speed_Grapher_characters#Katsuya_Shirogane):

> One of the Euphorics sent by Suitengu to retrieve Kagura from Saiga,
>   Katsuya Shirogane possesses the ability to stretch his body into any
>   imaginable form (making it at least seem as if his body is made of
>   rubber). Known as the Rubber Gimp, he was a ballet dancer who was
>   completely obsessed with the flexibility of rubber to the point of
>   breaking a young girl's arm for 'being too stiff'. His head was blown
>   off by Saiga using a piece of mirror to reflect his camera shot.
>   His Japanese voice actor is Takehito Koyasu and his English voice
>   actor is J. Michael Tatum. - Wikipedia